# Add together DataFrame rows with the same column values, but preserve ordering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
a  b  c
8  3  3
4  3  3
5  3  3
1  9  4
7  3  1
1  3  3
6  3  3
9  7  7
1  7  7
```

I want to get a DataFrame like this:

```
a  b  c
17 3  3
1  9  4
7  3  1
7  3  3
10 7  7
```

Essentially, I want to add together the values in column `a` when the values in columns `b` and `c` are the same, but I want to do that in sections. `groupby` wouldn't work here because it would put the DataFrame out of order. I have an iterative solution, but it is messy and not very Pythonic. Is there a way to do this using the functions of the DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do `shift` with `cumsum` create the subgroup by key

```
s = df[['b','c']].ne(df[['b','c']].shift()).all(1).cumsum()

out = df.groupby([s,df.b,df.c]).agg({'a':'sum','b':'first','c':'first'}).reset_index(drop=True)
    a  b  c
0  17  3  3
1   1  9  4
2   7  3  1
3   7  3  3
4  10  7  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(['b', 'c', df[['b', 'c']].diff().any(axis=1).cumsum()], as_index=False)['a'].sum()
```

Output:

```
   b  c   a
0  3  1   7
1  3  3  17
2  3  3   7
3  7  7  10
4  9  4   1
```

Comment: I think the downvote didn't like the "order" of my dataframe.  Which I think is asked in the question.  thanks @BENY.